# JTable Goto Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to implement a goto function. I have a JTable that has a few thousand rows and I want to be able to jump to a specified row number.

```
else if (BUTTON_GOTO.equals(command))
{
    int gotoLine = Integer.valueOf(gotoField.getText());            
    logTable.setRowSelectionInterval(gotoLine, gotoLine);
}
```

The code above will highlight the row I am looking for, but does not jump to it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**
There is a bug using the solution below where the application jumps a few lines short of the desired line. See the topic below for further details:

[Stack Overflow - Java JTable Goto Row Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632742/java-jtable-goto-row-bug)

Comment: By the way, you should be using `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Integer.valueOf()` unless you actually need an `Integer` object. Here you are creating the object and immediately converting it to the primitive `int`.

Comment: thanks for the tip. new to java :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
logTable.scrollRectToVisible(logTable.getCellRect(gotoLine, 0, true));
```

[getCellRect()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellRect%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29) returns a `Rectangle` which bounds the cell at the given row and column, and [scrollRectToVisible()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) tells the table's parent (which should be a JViewPort if you are using a JScrollPane) to scroll there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue which i solved with help of above
first I added gotoButton and text field

```
    JPanel gotoPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton gotoRowButton = new JButton("Goto Address");
    JTextField gotoAddressTextField = new JTextField();
    gotoAddressTextField.setColumns(12);
    gotoPanel.add(gotoRowButton);
    gotoPanel.add(gotoAddressTextField);

    frame.add(gotoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

then I added an actionListnener for the gotoRowButton

```
        gotoRowButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
             table.setRowSelectionInterval(
                 Integer.parseInt(gotoAddressTextField.getText(), 
                 Integer.parseInt(gotoAddressTextField.getText()));
            table.scrollRectToVisible(
            table.getCellRect(
              Integer.parseInt(gotoAddressTextField.getText()), 1, true)
      );
        }
    });
```

a visual of my work
[An image showing gotobutton and textfield and highlight of gotoRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afyNB.png)